# Does Basic User Authentication require 2-Phase communiation?

Tags: proxy, http, http-basic-authentication

My Application connects to the Internet to HTTP Services using boost::asio. Recently we added support for HTTP Proxys and Basic User Authentication. We implemented Basic User Authentication by just sending Authentication parameters with every HTTP call if a user configured a proxy in our program. Parameters are sent as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

```
Authorization: Basic <base64 Encoded username:password>
```

This works at least for one user and his proxy server. Other users report that their Proxy server replys with

> 407 Proxy Authentication Required

My guess is that some proxy servers accept 1 one phase authentication and that others don't. I do not find any information that a 2 Phase communication is requested where the access always is denied for the first call by returning 407 and that only a second call is accepted.

Our program yet does not retry the call if a 407 has been returned. Do we have to add this?

[I asked this question before on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558171/does-basic-user-authentication-require-2-phase-communiation) but did not get a sufficient answer.

Comment: At the least, it would be helpful to know which proxy servers you know to work well, and which you know to be a problem.

Comment: The on known to work is ASTARO Security Gateway V8 running Linux. We were not able to obtain information about the proxys not working yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As made clear in [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) (which you should have already read) authenticating to a proxy requires that you send the `Proxy-Authorization` header, not the `Authorization` header which is used to authenticate to origin servers. It sounds like the one "working" proxy server you found was actually "buggy."

Comment: Although we do not yet have 100% confirmation, according to our tests it seems that this was the problem.